# How to set ELECTRON_MIRROR in yarn4

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, yarnpkg

An error occurred when I used yarn4 to install Electron in the project. The specific error is as follows:

```
PS D:\code\ali-live-tools> yarn
➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.0.2
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 492ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0007: │ electron@npm:28.1.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0009: │ electron@npm:28.1.3 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xfs-381b520c\build.log)
➤ YN0000: · Failed with errors in 22s 178ms
```

The content in build.log is:

```
# This file contains the result of Yarn building a package (electron@npm:28.1.3)
# Script name: postinstall

RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.205.243.166:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\code\ali-live-tools\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at origin.emit (D:\code\ali-live-tools\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16)
```

I understand that this is caused by a timeout when accessing github resources. When I originally installed using npm, I often solved this problem by configuring `ELECTRON_MIRROR` in .npmrc, but when yarn was upgraded to version 4.x, it was no longer supported. Read the configuration from .npmrc. I checked the relevant information and found no relevant configuration.

Environment：

```
Node: 20.9.0
    Yarn: 4.0.2
    npm: 10.1.0
"electron": "^28.1.0"
```

I have also tried setting yarn config, but in version 4.x it will report an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSZVH.png)

I hope that `ELECTRON_MIRROR` can be configured through the .yarnrc.yml file, or other ways to facilitate team collaboration